# How to configure Rails 3.1 app from a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, configure

For example, I want to change rails settings when I require my gem to application.

If I simply put this line

```
Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = '/app/themes/default/assets'
```

into my gem, this does not change the settings. I think I need to use some rails hooks there.

Please help me guys

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to configure the path of the assets. When put in the proper place, they should load automatically. You need to define an "Engine". Have a look at a gem I made: https://github.com/iain/formalize-rails